# Am I eligible to apply US green Card under EB2 Category?

Tags: usa, greencard

I am working in USA with H1B VISA and pursuing Employment based green card. Below are my qualifications

1. I hold 4 years engineering degree with electrical and electronics department. I did my engineering in India.
2. I am working in IT industry and I have approximately 10 years of experience.
3. Out of 10 years 4 years in USA and 6 years in India.

With the above qualifications, Am I eligible to apply EB2 category?

Answer (score 1):

The eligibility is not for you, it's for you **and** the job.

The job must require at least 5 years of experience following a 4-year degree, or an advanced degree, and you must not include any degrees or experience earned while working on that job (if you're already in the position for which the petition is made).

Also, the degree must be relevant (don't know if EE degree is considered relevant for IT jobs).